# Getting warning note while trying to gather plan statistics of a query in oracle

Tags: oracle19c

I ran query `select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ ...` and post this I ran `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format => 'adaptive allstats last'));` for gathering the adaptive plan of the query, but it seems that I am missing something.
Can anyone tell me why am I getting this warning note at the end?

```
SQL_ID  5qus23w3vf7ry, child number 0
-------------------------------------

SELECT SYS_CONTEXT( 'USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA' ) FROM DUAL
 
Plan hash value: 1388734953
 
------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name | E-Rows |
------------------------------------------

|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |      |        |
|   1 |  FAST DUAL       |      |      1 |
------------------------------------------
 
Note

-----
   - Warning: basic plan statistics not available. These are only collected when:
       * hint 'gather_plan_statistics' is used for the statement or
       * parameter 'statistics_level' is set to 'ALL', at session or system level
```

Comment: Is this query used correctly **select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format => 'adaptive allstats last'));**?

Answer (score 1):

The missing statistics is because of of the optional parameter of `DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR`, SQL_ID. Per [the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_XPLAN.html#GUID-0EE333AF-E9AC-40A4-87D5-F6CF59D6C47B), "This parameter defaults to NULL in which case the plan of the last cursor executed by the session is displayed." If your IDE is silently executing SQL statements in the background in between user statements, then `DISPLAY_CURSOR` may pick up the wrong SQL_ID.

If your IDE is behaving that way, then it's safer to explicitly find the SQL_ID by querying GV$SQL. But even finding the precise SQL_ID can be a bit tricky sometimes. Depending on how the query was executed, the case may change. And The query against GV$SQL will return itself. So you probably want to search case insensitively, and also exclude the quine from the results:

```
select *
from gv$sql
where lower(sql_fulltext) like lower('%some unique string from your query%')
    and sql_fulltext not like '%quine%';
```

Then plug the relevant SQL_ID into the `DISPLAY_CURSOR` function:

```
select *
from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(sql_id => '0fhmc9n0tstxy', format => 'adaptive allstats last'));
```

Sorry I gave you bad advice in my last comment! The approach I recommended is simpler when it works, but it's not as robust as looking for the SQL_ID each time.

Comment: what if I executed the same query for more than one time, will that query use same SQL_ID every time or it can change?

Comment: @Rudra The SQL_ID will always be the same for the same query text. However, the text must be exactly the same, including spaces and case.

Comment: Okay got it. Thank you.